# Trouble Animating Quaternion Slerp

Tags: c++, quaternions

I am attempting to animate a slerp from q1 to q2 for my FPS camera. I have a target somewhere in my world and I want the camera to pan from its current axis to looking at my target. From what I understand the way to do this would be to calculate a quaternion representing my current `(axis, rotation)` and a second representing my final `(axis, rotation)` then every frame increment the amount I interpolate between the two from 0 to 1. Is this the correct idea?

What I don't understand is how to compute these beginning and end quaternions?

My camera is pretty standard and has the usual member variables:

```
glm::vec3 position,forward, up, yAxis, target;
glm::quat orientation;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:
`=` in this post represents mathematical equations, not assignments. (Sadly we have no mathmode on stackoverflow)

---

If your camera already has a member-quaternion, which describes its rotation, i suppose you have this quaternion. If not, you can use the same technique to find it as well:

If you know your rotational axis `vec3 r` and your angle `a` then your quaternion is `vec4 q = (cos(a/2), sin(a/2)*r)` (and any multiple of it). Your rotated vector is then `vec3 v' = q v inv(q)`.

I assume you want the camera to still point upwards, then you can split the rotation in two rotations, one around the global up axis (probably y) and one around the local horizontal-axis of the camera (probably x).
So your rotation is:

```
vec3 v' = g l v inv(l) inv(g)
g = (cos(a/2), sin(a/2)*(0,1,0))
l = (cos(b/2), sin(b/2)*(1,0,0))
```

with the addition of

```
vec3 normal(viewDirection) = g l (0,0,1) inv(l) inv(g)
```

(because later you want to have your cameras z-axis point in your viewDirection) you should be able to solve the equations.